# Передача файла из input через AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

Пытаюсь передать картинку через AJAX. Есть следующий код:

```
<input id="uploadimage" type="file" name="addImg" onchange="adderImg();" accept="image/*">

<script>
function adderImg(){
    var $input = $("#uploadimage").files;
    var fd = new FormData;

    fd.append('img', $input);
    alert(fb);//добавил для проверки
    $.ajax({
            url:"/parts_of_site/adderImgComment.php",
            type: "POST",
            processData: false, // Не обрабатываем файлы (Don't process the files)
            contentType: false,
            data: fd,
            success:function(data){
                $('#tempImg').html(data);
                //Console.log(data);
            }
    });
</script>
```

Собственно вопрос не по Ajax, там все вроде понятно. Картинка не передается в переменную `fd` Пишет, что она не определена. При этом `print_r($_FILES)` на стороне сервера выдает пустой массив. Где ошибка?

UPD:
Работал с кодом дальше и заметил, что ошибка еще раньше

```
var $input = $('#uploadimage').file;
alert($input);
```

Выводит `underfinded` То есть он даже не определяет выбранные файлы. Что делаю не так?

UPD2:
Весь косяк в строчке `var $input = $('#uploadimage').file;` Заменил на js-кую `$input = document.getElementsByName("addImg")[0].files[0];` и все заработало. Что было не так?))) Наверняка очень простой ответ, но я понять не могу.

Comment: fd и fb - разные переменные

Comment: Спасибо, поменял, но проблема не в этом. Просто файлы не определены изначально и AJAX передает пустые данные. Почему?